# How can I track a player's wins?

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I have a quiz game I built with sails, waterline and sockets. I'm in the process of transferring the DB from local to mysql. What I can't figure out is how can I track a player's win using an incremented integer in the DB.

So far, my user modal generates this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ether",
    "email": "ether@gh.com",
    "password": "sha1$b39f3d56$1$ebd354e8af83b21be4de4ffee90b10ed746553de",
    "status": "online",
    "score": 0,
    "totalwins": 0,
    "createdAt": "2017-08-16T17:22:04.879Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-08-16T17:22:05.153Z",
    "id": 31,
    "ip": "::1"
  }
]
```

As a user plays over the course of a day, I want to track the amount of times they have been declared a winner. I check for the winner in my `quiz.js` file here:

```
if (highScore > 0) {
        if (isDraw) {
          $('#winner-message').html('We have a draw. Well done!');
          $('#winner-image').addClass('no-one-wins');
        }
        else {
          $('#winner-message').html('And the winner is... <strong>' + players[scoreIndex] + '</strong>!');
          $('#winner-image').css('background-image', 'url("' + $('#status-table tbody tr').eq(scoreIndex).find('.name').attr('data-avatar') + '")');
        }
      }
      else {
        $('#winner-message').html('And the winner is... <strong>no one</strong> :-(');
        $('#winner-image').addClass('no-one-wins');
      }
    }
```

How could I make it so I can update that field with `+1` when there is a winner? I feel like I'll have to reference it in my model like this, but I'm not sure.

```
winner: function (inputs, cb){

    },
```

Appreciate any help and insight!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the id of the player in a variable `playerId`, you can write some code something like this:

`Players.find(id: playerId).exec(function(error,player) {
    if (error)
       (handle error)
    player.totalwins = player.totalwins+1;
    delete player.id
    Players.update(playerId,player)
})`

Comment: Would I be setting the variable in my User model, then running this code?

Comment: This code is updating the player record. You could update the User record instead if you want to